# MediaPlayer plays when page loads then pauses and waits for user to hit play

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming, playback, internet-radio

I am working on an app for my school media suit and am trying to add the radio's internet stream to the app. I currently have it connected and playing but when I load the radio's page in the app the music starts playing for about 3 seconds then pauses and waits until you hit play. It will not play for about 10 seconds after pausing even if you hit play.

```
package edu.calu.sai.studentmediaapp;

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Radio extends AppCompatActivity
{
    protected final String url = "http://184.154.90.186:8002/stream";

    protected Boolean isPlaying = false;

    MediaPlayer player = null;
    ImageView play;
    ImageView pause;
    AudioManager audio;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.radio);
        initUI();
        initPlayer();
        audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
                audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                                         AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
                return true;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
                audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                                         AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
    private void initUI()
    {
        play = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.play);
        pause = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pause);
    }
    private void initPlayer()
    {
        if(player == null)
        {
            player = new MediaPlayer();
            try
            {
                player.setDataSource(url);
                player.prepareAsync();
                player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
                    {
                        player.start();
                        isPlaying = true;
                    }
                });
            } catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Error here:" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    public void back(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void dial(View v)
    {
        try {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:(724) 938-3000"));
            startActivity(callIntent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException)
        {}

    }
    public void stationControl(View v)
    {
        if(isPlaying)
        {
            player.pause();
            isPlaying = !isPlaying;
            play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
            player.start();
            isPlaying = !isPlaying;
            play.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help.